# Validate xml result in unit test?

Tags: c#, xml, unit-testing, nunit

I have three classes - ConvertToXMLElement, ConvertToClass, SerialisableClass

ConvertToXMLElement has a function which takes in an instance of SerialisableClass and returns an XmlElement representing the classes values, ConvertToClass has a function which takes in an XmlElement and returns a SerialisableClass.

I'm trying to write a unit test which validates the XmlElement returned from the ConvertToXMLElement to ensure the XmlElement can be converted into the correct class by ConvertToClass.

Right now the only way I can imagine doing it is by getting ConvertToClass to try and convert the XmlElement to a class.

But this means there's a dependency between the two classes on each other in the unit tests, ideally the unit test doesn't have to care about the other class when validating this classes functions.

Comment: You have to fake the class you have dependency on to return the result you require from it. That way you can test your "XmlElement" class without actually running the codes in your ConvertToClass

Comment: What application will be using the XML files you're generating? It would be ideal if you could write your test using the slurper-parser the consuming application uses. Another option would be to serialize fixed data and compare the result against a fixed known-good XML file. Obviously requires more maintenance... Finally, don't be afraid to serialize then deserialize using your classes. It _is_ a good idea.. so long as you've got other tests to back that symmetrical test up.

Answer (score 1):

Isolation is the standard in unit testing, but testing serialization / deserialization together is not totally unacceptable, IMO.

It depends on who will use the serialized data. If it's only used within your two classes, then it's a relatively safe shortcut to test them together.

OTOH, if the data must be in some special format so that it can be used by other programs, then you absolutely need to test the two stages separately. That implies that you will actually examine the serialized XML to determine if it meets the external requirement and you will create XML for use in testing that meets the same standard.

Of course, you can separate the two even if it isn't strictly necessary, but that's typically a lot more work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to isolate your code. Your code will have dependencies always, so its our job to isolate the code when we are doing the Unit testing as well. Linking you a couple of links to help you understand how to do it.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549174.aspx
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/understand-stub-mock-and-fake-in-unit-testing/